# database.execSQL(sql) method crashes my emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I tried to run my code a couple of times and it always crashes on database.execSQL(sql). I managed to locate "sqlite-test-1.db" in my storage and deleted it but it does not help.

This is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.education.abcdefghijken.sqlitetest

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem

import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

private const val TAG = "MainActivity"

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val database = baseContext.openOrCreateDatabase("sqlite-test-1.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null)
        var sql = "CREATE TABLE contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)"
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: sql is $sql")
        database.execSQL(sql)

        sql = "INSERT INTO contacts(name, phone, email) VALUES ('tim', 2344324, 'Tim@email.com')"
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: sql is $sql")
        database.execSQL(sql)

        val values = ContentValues().apply { // key value pairs
            put("name", "Fred")
            put("phone", 12345)
            put("email", "fred@mail.com")
        }

        val generatedId = database.insert("contacts", null, values)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: record added with id $generatedId")

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what my logcat looks like filtered with /mainactivity:

```
2020-05-10 22:56:16.660 9313-9313/? D/MainActivity: onCreate: sql is CREATE TABLE contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)
```

Full logcat:

```
2020-05-10 22:56:16.660 9313-9313/? D/MainActivity: onCreate: sql is CREATE TABLE contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)
2020-05-10 22:56:16.660 9313-9313/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table contacts already exists
2020-05-10 22:56:16.661 9313-9313/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-05-10 22:56:16.667 9313-9313/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.education.abcdefghijken.sqlitetest, PID: 9313
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.education.abcdefghijken.sqlitetest/com.education.abcdefghijken.sqlitetest.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts already exists (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
```

I have deleted all the files relating to 'sqlite-test-1.db' but it keeps saying that the table exists, where do I actually find the location for the database file or any other related files when I use the `openOrCreateDatabase` method? Thank you.

P.S: I'm actually following a Udemy course and it seems like most people don't have this problem after looking through the FAQs.

Comment: There's no need to do that manually. You can simply clear your app's data on its page in the device Settings. Uninstalling your app would also clear that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems table already created;

Did you try this:

```
var sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)"
```

instead of:

```
var sql = "CREATE TABLE contacts(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone INTEGER, email TEXT)"
```